# Limits on File Count for Azure Blob Storage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

Currently, I have a large set of text files which contain (historical) raw data from various sensors.  New files are received and processed every day.  I'd like to move this off of an on-premises solution to the cloud.

Would Azure's Blob storage be an appropriate mechanism for this volume of small(ish) private files? or is there another Azure solution that I should be pursuing?

Relevent Data (no pun intended) & Requirements-

- The data set contains a millions files of mostly small files, for a total of near 400gb.  The average file size is around 50kb, but some files could exceed 40mb.
- I need to maintain the existing data set for posterity's sake.
- New files would be uploaded daily, and then processed once.  Processing would be handled by Background Workers reading files off a queue.
- Certain files would be downloaded / reviewed / reprocessed after the initial processing.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're asking. Blob storage has no specific limit on number of objects; just limited by the 500TB storage account size limit.

Comment: I just would like to make sure I'm using the right tool for the right job.  I'm guessing it CAN be used as a file system, is the right (best) tool for the job... SHOULD it be used as a file system. I CAN (and have) used a screwdriver to hammer in a nail, but it is not the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me elaborate more on David's comments.

As David mentioned, there's no limit on number of objects (files) that you can store in Azure Blob Storage. The limit is of the size of the storage account which currently is 500TB. As long as you stay in this limit you will be good. Further, you can have 100 storage accounts in an Azure Subscription so essentially the amount of data that you will be able to store is practically limitless.

I do want to mention one more thing though. It seems that the files that are uploaded in blob storage are once processed and then kind of archived. For this I suggest you take a look at [`Azure Cool Blob Storage`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/introducing-azure-cool-storage/). It is essentially meant for this purpose only where you want to store objects that are not frequently accessible yet when you need those objects they are accessible almost immediately. The advantage of using Cool Blob Storage is that writes and storage is cheaper as compared to Hot Blob Storage accounts however the reads are expensive (which makes sense considering their intended use case).

So a possible solution would be to save the files in your Hot Blob Storage accounts. Once the files are processed, they are moved to Cool Blob Storage. This Cool Blob Storage account can be in the same or different Azure Subscription.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm guessing it CAN be used as a file system, is the right (best) tool for the job.

Yes, Azure Blobs Storage can be used as cloud file system.

> The data set contains a millions files of mostly small files, for a total of near 400gb. The average file size is around 50kb, but some files could exceed 40mb.

As David and Gaurav Mantri mentioned, Azure Blob Storage could meet this requirement.

> I need to maintain the existing data set for posterity's sake.

Data in Azure Blob Storage is durable. You could reference the [SERVICE LEVEL AGREEMENTS of Storage](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/legal/sla/storage/v1_2/).

> New files would be uploaded daily, and then processed once. Processing would be handled by Background Workers reading files off a queue.

You can use Azure Function to do the file processing work. Since it will do once a day, you could add a TimerTrigger Function.

```
//This function will be executed once a day
public static void TimerJob([TimerTrigger("0 0 0 * * *")] TimerInfo timerInfo)
{
    //write the processing job here
}
```

> Certain files would be downloaded / reviewed / reprocessed after the initial processing.

Blobs can be downloaded or updated at anytime you want.

In addition, if your data processing job is very complicated, you also could store your data in Azure Data Lake Store and do the data processing job using Hadoop analytic frameworks such as MapReduce or Hive. Microsoft Azure HDInsight clusters can be provisioned and configured to directly access data stored in Data Lake Store.

Here are the differences between Azure Data Lake Store and Azure Blob Storage.

[Comparing Azure Data Lake Store and Azure Blob Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-comparison-with-blob-storage)